# GoLang 1.21.1 fatal error: found bad pointer in Go heap (incorrect use of unsafe or cgo?)

Tags: flutter, go, pointers, cgo

I have an application in Flutter, which uses (through ffi).dll(windows)/.dylib(mac) written in Go and then compiled with CGO. And use protobuf to comunicate between the sides to use the marshal and unmarshal.

Up to Go version 1.20.8 everything works fine. But when I upgraded to 1.21.1 I started having errors with pointers, only in the compiled versions. If I test the code only on GO there is no problem. But the version compiled within the Flutter application seems to try to access memory addresses that have already been freed, or something like that.

Examples of errors:
fatal error: found bad pointer in Go heap (incorrect use of unsafe or cgo?)
runtime: g 18: unexpected return pc for runtime.cgocallback called from 0x124a66fe1

Has anyone ever had something similar?

I've already tried to simplify the code, and change the way I declare the pointers, but the error continues.

Comment: You might want to [report](https://github.com/golang/go/issues) that or check whether it already has been reported.